# Painting pre-primed doors and trim

Tags: paint

When I bought my house everything was painted, trim, doors, baseboard etc.

Now I am developing my basement and ordered trim and doors from the same supplier. They all came pre-primed so I assumed I can just use a finish paint.

I checked what the builder left behind and I found that the painter used this paint for the doors and trim: http://www.homedepot.ca/product/behr-premium-plusltsupgtreglt-supgt-interior-semi-gloss-enamel-paint-ultra-/938906

Which is a paint and primer in 1. As the reviews are good and I would like the colors to be the same, is it safe to use this paint and do everything just 1 coat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use the paint/primer paint in the place of paint.

If you go with the same brand, you should be able to get the color code off the lid and any hardware store that sells the paint will be able to mix the same color again for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just painted all my of trim this weekend, if it has a shiny gloss finish already on there, sanding them down a little bit may help you to only use one coat.

Comment: One coat with trim is fine if it is a thick coat and given you have to retouch the nail holes.  Now with doors you need 2+ coats for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your finish work is only as good as your primer I always prime factory primed material but my primes is only as good as there's since it was applied first

Comment: So why do you re-prime factory primed wood if re-priming can't improve it?